# How does readdir() work in conjunction with rename()?

Tags: c

I have written a function to rename files in a directory so that they are named in a numerical sequence. Unfortunately, this function seems to throw away some files and renames some. Probably, I don't understand the logic behind readdir() and rename(). Can anybody help, here is the extract of my code;

```
while(((entry->readdir(dirp))!=NULL)
{
  strcpy(t1_string,entry->d_name);
  exception1=strcmp(entry->d_name,".");
  exception2=strcmp(entry->d_name,"..");
  exception3=strcmp(entry->d_name,".svn");
  if((exception1!=0)&&(exception2!=0)&&(exception3!=0))
  {
    token2=strchr(t1_string,'.'); //extension part
    num_files++;
    if(num_files%4==1)
        utt++;
    sprintf(utt_n,"%d",utt);
    strcpy(newfilename, utt_s); //utt_s is a constant string
    strcat(newfilename,utt_n);
    strcat(newfilename,token2);
    rename(entry->d_name,newfilename);
  }
} //End of the while loop
```

Comment: replace the line `rename(entry->d_name,newfilename);` by `printf("mv -i %s %s\n" ,entry->d_name, newfilename);` end see what it attempts to do. Then: run the created script.

Comment: The desired new names come is the desired order, but the old names come up in a disrupted manner, no sequence is observed. Let me search for an alternative way of doing this.

Comment: Replace the bunch of strcat()s by a single snprintf() and make sure that newfilename is large enough.

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely due to a race condition; you're essentially modifying a data structure while iterating over it. The data structure is the file system's idea of the names of the files in the directory, of course.

As pointed out in a comment, there's even a warning for this exact case in the Open Group's spec page for [`readdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> If a file is removed from or added to the directory after the most recent call to `opendir()` or `rewinddir()`, whether a subsequent call to `readdir()` returns an entry for that file is unspecified.

A better approach would be to do it in two phases:

1. Collect all the names.
2. Do the desired renames.

Of course you have to be prepared for renames to fail, since other processes can rename or delete files in parallel with you.

Comment: `scandir` (part of POSIX.1-2008)  can be helpful for phase 1.

Comment: In fact the manual page for readdir, on my system anyway directly calls out this risk: If a file is removed from or added to the directory after the most recent call to opendir() or rewinddir(), it is unspecified whether a subsequent call to readdir() returns an entry for that file.

Comment: I see, so the files won't be renamed properly no matter how much I try using readdir(). Let me search for an alternative to this problem.

Comment: The answer above is correct.  You need to collect all the file names first, *before* you do any renames.  You can do this with readdir(), but you will likely find that using scandir() is easier.